# Throw validation exception shows the given data is invalid

Tags: php, laravel

i'm using laravel 5.8 and i want to catch validation error with validation exception, this is my code:

```
 $attr = $request->data['attributes'];
        $validator = Validator::make($attr,[
            'nama' => 'required|string',
            'scope' => 'required|string'
        ]);

try{
    if($validator->fails()){
        //$err = ValidationException::withMessages($validator->errors()->getMessages());
        throw new ValidationException($validator);
    }            
}catch(ValidationException $e){
       return response()->json([
           'status'=> 'error',
           'code' => 400,
           'detail' => $e->getMessage()
       ], 400);
}
```

but it didn't show validation error massage, just showing 'the given data is invalid.'

the detail should be:

```
detail:[
    'scope':['Scope field is required']
]
```

UPDATE FIXED:

just call `$e->errors()`

Comment: it's not exception error. it`s validation failing error.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this Code

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'nama' => 'required|string',
        'scope' => 'required|string'
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => false,
            'ErrorCode' => 1,
            'error' => $validator->errors()],
                 400);
                   }
```

Comment: no, i want to show it within try catch block (ValidationException)

Comment: @Arun P sorry for mistakenly editing. Don`t know how to revert it back.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get all validation error messages

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'nama' => 'required|string',
    'scope' => 'required|string'
]);
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return response()->json([
        'status' => false,
        'ErrorCode' => 1,
        'error' => $validator->errors()->messages();]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using laravel 5.8 so you can create sperate validation file like `FilenameRequest.php` by `php artisan make:request FilenameRequest`

After creating request file your request file is look like this:

```
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{

        return [
            'scope'   => 'required|max:3',
        ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'scope'       => 'Scope field is required'
    ];
}
```

And in your controller method you can simply use this request file like this

```
public function store(FilenameRequest $request) {

}
```